# Raphael js - draw path without intersections

Tags: svg, raphael, intersection

I use svg library **raphaeljs** to draw polygons. I do it like this:

```
path.attr({path: "
M 301 248 613 283 588 533 370 497 232 382 232 382 Z
"})
```

User clicks on canvas in some place and then I redraw polygon according coordinates of the new point. Is it possible to deny intersections between lines in one polygon?
**UPDATE**: you can try [this](http://davidbau.com/javascript/polygon-drawing.html) as an example. I don't want to allow self-intersections. Source code could be found [here](http://davidbau.com/javascript/learn/10-polygon.html#/polygon-drawing).

Comment: Do you mean self-intersection?  It would be helpful if you provided a [MCVE].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I added more details. Yes, self-intersections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to know whether Raphael has some embed functionality to find intersections between line segments. Finally I used this approach based on multiplication of vectors:

```
function intersection(ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2, bx1, by1, bx2, by2){
   var v1 = (bx2-bx1)*(ay1-by1)-(by2-by1)*(ax1-bx1);
   var v2 = (bx2-bx1)*(ay2-by1)-(by2-by1)*(ax2-bx1);
   var v3 = (ax2-ax1)*(by1-ay1)-(ay2-ay1)*(bx1-ax1);
   var v4 = (ax2-ax1)*(by2-ay1)-(ay2-ay1)*(bx2-ax1);
   return (v1*v2<0) && (v3*v4<0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid self-intersecting polygons, surely all you have to do is check that the line segment you are about to add **doesn't cross any of the other line segments in the polygon**.

So it is just a matter of adding a line intersection test and checking the latest segment against all the previous ones.

You can search the web for the algorithm for a line intersection test. You won't have trouble finding it.